# How to test rxjava chaining?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java2

Hi i have created implementation that uses flatmap to chain two requests together with the final outcome being a response object returned from the second request and wondering if it is possible to mock these two chained response objects?

Here is the main code

```
delegator.requestOne(requestData)
                .flatMap ({  response ->
                    if(response.isSuccessful){
                        cookieStorage.saveSessionCookies(response.header(cookieStorage.COOKIE_HEADER_NAME)!!)
                    }
                    delegator.requestTwo

                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(object : SingleObserver<ResponseTwo>() {
                    @Override
                    fun onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    fun onSuccess(responseTwo :ResponseTwo) {
                        callback.onSuccess(responseTwo)
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }
                });
```

If this did not have a flatmap and handled just one request/response i would write the below using mockito

```
Mockito.when(network.makeReq()).thenReturn(Single.just(responseOne));
```

But how can i do something like this:

```
Mockito.when(foodHygieneController.getLocalAuthorities()).thenReturn(Single.just(requestOne)).thenReturn(requestTwo)??
```

assuming requestOne and RequestTwo are hard coded mock values of my choosing

Answer (score 2):

You simply mock every request (call to a mocked object) that is part of your Rx chain. 
In your case:

```
Mockito.when(delegator.requestOne(...)).thenReturn(...)
Mockito.when(delegator.requestTwo(...)).thenReturn(...) / Mockito.when(delegator.requestTwo(responseOne)).thenReturn(...)
```

You can then test that the 'output' (emitted items) from that chain are what you expect them to be, for example with a [TestSubscriber](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html), or in your example, that `callback` is called with the `ResponseTwo` you expect / have mocked.

The Rx chain will operate in your test exactly as it does when running the code 'normally'.

What you cannot do is mock the behaviour of the Rx chain, e.g. you cannot mock how `flatMap{}` operates.